# Amazon feed - upload product with variation price and quantity

Tags: xml, laravel, amazon-selling-partner-api

I want to know can I create Amazon product with API, and in same feed to add variation price and quantity, because now I am adding one feed to create product, after that one to make relationship with variants, after that one feed for adding price and at the end one to add inventory. This takes so much time, and I want to know is there faster way to add it with AMAZON SP API.

Comment: Each request to Amazon is an HTTP Request and then you get a response.  The time should not change significantly if you make one request or two (like you currently are doing).

Comment: But I want to know is it possible to add in same feed price, quantity, variation image and not in all separated requests

Comment: How would you be able to tell which response would be for each request?  What would the advantage be for combining?  You are trying to make the problem harder instead of easier.

Comment: I dont mean to put all requests in one, I am asking is it possible in <Product></Product> add Price, Quantity and ProductImage. Now for everything I need to create new feed

Comment: Only if a single query supports the results you are looking for.